# Are mimikaki for real?

Tags: japan, souvenirs

In Japan, a popular souvenir is [*mimikaki*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_pick) (耳かき) - a pick for cleaning the ears. They often come in decorative packaging, and have little trinkets dangling from the handle (e.g. a tiny wooden shoe). My understanding is that people buy them to give to their relatives.

My question is: is this a serious gift, or is it supposed to be funny? And is it common to give them to friends and teachers too?

Comment: There's a Japanese-language article on it, so at the very least it's not a myth made up by non-Japanese people: [耳掻き](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%80%B3%E6%8E%BB%E3%81%8D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't say if it is a common gift to give to your teacher, at least I would not do, but mimikaki is a perfectly fine gift if it is decorative enough. There's nothing funny or shy about it, this is what it is. Cleaning ears to your loved ones is a way to express your affection in Japan and mimikaki work there like nothing else.

Comment: Yup. A friend of mine once received a silver mimikaki as a gift when flying JAL Business Class.

Comment: Just to be clear: if you give someone a mimikaki, do you expect them to use it?

Comment: @z0r of course.